# How to Configure v3 Northwind Database in manifest.json in SAPUI5?

Tags: odata, sapui5, northwind

I am trying to build a crud operation with the svc url:
 http://services.odata.org/V3/northwind/northwind.svc

Whenever I am going to create a new data I am getting the following error in console: "The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed403,Forbidden,{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Forbidden"}}}"
Does it have the facility to be updated or it is some thing else?!!
I am uploading the manifest.json file and a little error showing(though its not stopping the app from running). [manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Xf2.jpg)

```
...
"sap.app": {
  "mainService": {
    "uri": "/Northwind",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "odataversion": "3.0"
    }
  }      
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no odata v3 support by sapui5. possible values for the `odataversion` property in the `manifest.json` are `2.0` and `4.0`. those are the by sapui5 supported odata versions.

please try to describe the odata service in the `manifest.json` this way:

```
{
  ...
  "sap.app": {
    ...
    "dataSources": {
      "dataSourceName": {
        "uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
  "models": {
    ...
      "modelName": {
        "dataSource": "dataSourceName"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but if I use v2 then also its showing like this:      
   The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed403,Forbidden,{
"error": {"code": "", "message": {"lang": "en-US", "value": "Forbidden"}}

Comment: does the to the post added code sample work in the application?

Comment: please try to apply the code sample of the post to the manifest.json of the application.